# Python - add to locals of calling

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have an application which allows the user to start an interactive Python session. Accordingly, my important functions are added to the locals collection:

```
code.interact( local = get_my_functions() )
```

This is so a naive user can just type the functions without worrying about imports:

```
>>> my_function( ... )
```

(Nb: This is part of the UI and does not preclude an advanced user from importing my application as a library and using it normally)

I wish to achieve the same functionality with the Jupyter notebook. This essentially involves the same thing - adding my functions to the locals of the interactive session.

Since I cannot use `code.interact( locals = ... )` I have considered defining the following at the start of the script:

```
def add_builtins()
    builtins.__dict__.update( get_my_functions() )
```

And then calling `add_builtins` in the notebook. However I can see why this might be considered bad practice: I only wish to add to the locals for the interactive session, not override the builtins throughout the session.

I have also considered:

```
globals().update( get_my_functions() )
```

But this necessitates that this line itself is present in the notebook code, in order to retrieve the pertinent `globals` dictionary, which is messy.

Is there a better alternative?